# Wordpress product page scoring description

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi I have a website and want to add on my product page a scoring visual similar to this site

https://www.thehoopsgeek.com/shoe-reviews/puma-stewie-2/

You can see on the Category performance ratings and weight and size. Those are something i would like to have on my site

Anyone kindly help me on the right direction to achieve that? Ive search for quite some time and cannot find a good answer.

Thanks!

Something similar to this site
https://www.thehoopsgeek.com/shoe-reviews/puma-stewie-2/

Comment: Hi and welcome! Your question is very broad so I don't think anyone can give a specific answer to that. Design decissions are opinion based and there's a million ways to go about this. Are you looking for layouts or styling for a specific HTML element?